# Coefficient of Fourier cosine & value of full series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I am working on a simple Fourier question from an introductory PDE text by John Davis.

The question begins with a graph that can be reduced into piecewise:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  &0 \leq x < 0.5 \\
0,  &0.5 \leq x \leq 1, \  -1 \leq x \leq -0.5\\
-1, &-0.5 < x < 0 
\end{cases}$$

> **Questions:**
>   (a) Find the value of $a_{99}$, the 99th Fourier cosine coefficient for $-3 < x < 3$ 
>   (b) Find the value of the full Fourier series at $x = 0, x = 1$ and also $x = -1$.

Here are my attempts at the solutions so far:

---

(a) The text provides this formula for $a_n$,

$$a_n = \frac {2}{l} \int_{0}^{l} f(x) \cos (\frac{n \pi x}{l}) dx.$$

After assigning $f(x) = \pm 1$, that is by ignoring the $f(x) = 0$ from the piecewise, putting in $l = 3, n = 99$ and $ f(x) = \pm 1$, I get the answer $a_{99} = \pm 3.7463 x 10^{-12}$ from TI-84 graphic calculator. Am I correct, especially in assigning $f(x) = \pm 1$?

---

(b) Here I am totally lost except getting these lengthy formulas from text, and any help would be very much appreciated:

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{2}a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [a_n \cos (\frac{n \pi x}{l}) + b_n \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{l})].\\
a_n &= \frac{1}{l} \int_{-l}^{l}f(x) \cos (\frac{n \pi x}{l}) dx,\\
b_n &= \frac{1}{l} \int_{-l}^{l}f(x) \sin (\frac{n \pi x}{l}) dx,
{}\end{align}$$

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: f(x) is an odd function (sketch it). What does that tell you about $a_{99}$ and $a_n$? For part (b) note that the value of the fourier series at a point is the average value of the function at that point. No integrals required.

Comment: @Paul : Thanks. I think I pretty much understand (a) from you. On (b), by average, do you mean the average of value of $f$ and the value of its $f_{even}, f_{odd}$ or $f_{shift}$? Thanks again.

Comment: If a function is discontinuous at a point then the value of the fourier series at that point is its average value (of f(x+) and f(x-) where x+ denotes the limit from the right and x- the limit from the left at x).

Comment: This has nothing to do with PDEs, at least at first sight.

Comment: So Fourier analysis is no part of PDE but one stand-alone branch of mathematics? Thanks.

Comment: @A.Magnus, that is correct. Fourier analysis is a self contained subject. It happens to be a tool which is very useful for solving PDE's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is an odd function, hence we simply have $a_n=0$.

Using standard theorems on the [pointwise convergence of Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series), we have that the Fourier series of $f(x)$ equals zero both in $x=0$ and in $x=\pm 1$ (even without computing it!).

Comment: Thanks! I was alerted belatedly by email of your response. I have up-voted and green check-marked. Thanks again!